# App Crashes when Tweet button Clicked by giving SIGKILL error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, tweets

I was using Twitter Oath for twitter sharing, suddenly the same code is getting crashed when i tap Tweet button.

App is Crashing while twitter oath is sending update request.

here is code of sharing option

```
-(IBAction)ShareWithTwitter:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"Tweet !!!");

if(!_engine)
{
    _engine = [[SA_OAuthTwitterEngine alloc] initOAuthWithDelegate:self];
    _engine.consumerKey    =kOAuthConsumerKey;

    _engine.consumerSecret = kOAuthConsumerSecret;  
}
else
{

    _engine = [[SA_OAuthTwitterEngine alloc] initOAuthWithDelegate:self];
    _engine.consumerKey    =kOAuthConsumerKey;

    _engine.consumerSecret = kOAuthConsumerSecret;  


}

UIViewController *controller = [SA_OAuthTwitterController controllerToEnterCredentialsWithTwitterEngine:_engine delegate:self];

if (controller)
{
    [self presentModalViewController: controller animated: YES];
}


}
```

And this code is for Tweet  !! (where app is crashing).

```
-(IBAction)updateTwitter:(id)sender
{
activityIndicatorView.hidden=NO;
activityIndicatorView.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray;
[activityIndicatorView startAnimating];

[tweetTextField resignFirstResponder];

NSString *strToPostOnTwitter = @"Hello Happy New Year to All !!!";

NSLog(@"String to Post is : %@",strToPostOnTwitter);

//Twitter Integration Code Goes Here
[_engine sendUpdate:strToPostOnTwitter];

//btnTwitter.hidden = YES;

}
```

Comment: Hey!!! R u not getting my Notification.?

Comment: worked for me.....
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8576877/mgtwitterengine-crash-in-ios5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are testing it on iOS 5, many times, it will not even generate a token properly. The twitter engine you are using works only with iOS4.

Now coming to your code, as the token is not generated and without it, you will be trying to post the message and so it crashed. I did a lot of research for the past one month and I decided to implement this way:
If is iOS 5 device in which you are running the app, use twitter framework. else use MGTwitterEngine.

Look for the following URL's
http://iosdevelopertips.com/core-services/ios-5-twitter-framework-part-1.html
http://iosdevelopertips.com/core-services/ios-5-twitter-framework-part-2.html
http://iosdevelopertips.com/core-services/ios-5-twitter-framework-%E2%80%93-part-3.html

Comment: Is there any tutorial or sample code for Twitter Framework ??

Comment: Thanks for links but third link has not any tutorial, let me try the remaining Two. Thanks again.

Comment: First two links are sufficient for you. third one is just for information.