# Application Crashed at when i tweet in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

Application crashed at line ....

```
[AppDel.engine getFollowedTimelineSinceID:1 startingAtPage:1 count:100];
[AppDel.engine sendUpdate:textView.text];
```

Please help me ....i am trying resolve it from last day....

Comment: which classes are u using for twitter engine..? on which iOS..?

Comment: hey which api u use for twitter ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `MGTwitterEngine` for twitter implementation in iOS app. For iOS 5 and above it crashes. You need to replace the twitter connection url's..

Its a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8576877/mgtwitterengine-crash-in-ios5) question, in this link new url's are given for TwitterEngine, replace them works fine for both iOS 5 above and below iOS 5.